In pseudo-codes, how to get newline in the same state?
I want to generate a pseudo-code similar to the image: 
Here's what I tried (I modified a bit the content of the code, but the idea is clear). In Inputs, splitting components in different lines with this structure in the image is exactly what I want. I tried to use $\par$ but it changes the spacing between lines.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm, algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\CB}{\mathcal{B}}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State \textbf{Inputs:} variable 1, \par
    Threshold: variable 2, \par
    label budget: variable3
    \State \textbf{Initialization:} History: $H \gets \emptyset$ \par
    $\cB_0$: All subsets of $\Iintv{1,n}$ 
\For{$k=1, \ldots, n$}
        \For{$S \subseteq [k]$}
        \State $\textbf{weight}(\cB_k) \gets \textsc{WeightEstimator}(\cB_{S,k+1})$ \par
        $\textbf{weight}(\cB_{S \cup \{k\},k+1}) \gets \textsc{WeightEstimator}(\cB_{S \cup \{k\},k+1})$
        \EndFor
        \EndFor
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}

This code gives the following:

As you see when we get a new line in input, it's not well organized.
Thank you,

You can wrap text in a \parbox, \pbox (from pbox package) or tabular-environment to include line breaks. Can you show us what you have already?

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please show some code in order to clarify which packages and document class you use.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please not close immediately the question for a member since today in this community.

Please let me know if I have to explain more my problem.

@Bubaya, thank you for your answer, I'll upload the result of the pseudo-code I get.

Does this answer your question? break an long line in an algorithm

That one is for algorithm2e and not for algpseudocode, but the use of \parbox is the same.

@Guesttilunderstandingnature Can you please add a compilable test file to your question, which includes a class and the necessary packages? There are several, partially incompatible, packages for algorithm. It is important to know which one you are using so that any solution you'll get will work for you.

@Marijn is that a new environment I need to define for pseudo-code?

I edited the question, thank you all for your patience.

@Guesttilunderstandingnature Unfortunately we can't compile your example, we don't have your preamble.tex file.

Sorry, I missed that. In preamble.tex I only used the command defined in the edit version of the question.

You should then replace the line \input{preamble} with \newcommand{\CB}{\mathcal{B}}, if it also reproduces the issue.

@Guesttilunderstandingnature you don't need to define any new environments, to apply the solution in the duplicate for your situation would be something like \State \textbf{Inputs:} \parbox[t]{5cm}{variable 1,\\     Threshold: variable 2,\\     label budget: variable3}

Using \parbox, as suggested, might have undesired consequences on vertical spacing.
Here's a possibility that could be good if there are just a few of such occasions.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm, algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\cB}{\mathcal{B}}
\newcommand{\Iintv}[1]{(#1)}% ???

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}

%local command for alignments
\newcommand{\PH}[1]{\noindent\hphantom{\textbf{#1:} }\ignorespaces}

\caption{Algorithm}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \State \textbf{Inputs:} variable 1,\par
         \PH{Inputs}      Threshold: variable 2, \par
         \PH{Inputs}      label budget: variable 3
  \State \textbf{Initialization:} History: $H \gets \emptyset$ \par
         \PH{Initialization}      $\cB_0$: All subsets of $\Iintv{1,n}$ 
  \For{$k=1, \dots, n$}
    \For{$S \subseteq [k]$}
      \State $\textbf{weight}(\cB_k) \gets \textsc{WeightEstimator}(\cB_{S,k+1})$
      \State $\textbf{weight}(\cB_{S \cup \{k\},k+1}) \gets 
             \textsc{WeightEstimator}(\cB_{S \cup \{k\},k+1})$
    \EndFor
  \EndFor
\end{algorithmic}

\end{algorithm}

\end{document}


A more general solution:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm, algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\cB}{\mathcal{B}}
\newcommand{\Iintv}[1]{(#1)}% ???

\NewDocumentEnvironment{Spec}{m}{%
  \renewcommand{\\}{\par\noindent\hphantom{\textbf{#1:\@} }\ignorespaces}%
  \textbf{#1:\@} \ignorespaces
}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Algorithm}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \State
    \begin{Spec}{Inputs}
      variable 1, \\
      Threshold: variable 2, \\
      label budget: variable 3
    \end{Spec}
  \State
    \begin{Spec}{Initialization}
      History: $H \gets \emptyset$ \\
      $\cB_0$: All subsets of $\Iintv{1,n}$ 
    \end{Spec}
  \For{$k=1, \dots, n$}
    \For{$S \subseteq [k]$}
      \State $\textbf{weight}(\cB_k) \gets \textsc{WeightEstimator}(\cB_{S,k+1})$
      \State $\textbf{weight}(\cB_{S \cup \{k\},k+1}) \gets 
             \textsc{WeightEstimator}(\cB_{S \cup \{k\},k+1})$
    \EndFor
  \EndFor
\end{algorithmic}

\end{algorithm}

\end{document}


